# Проблема при создании калькулятора

Tags: javascript, калькулятор

Проблема в том, что при сложение двух чисел (создается сначала первое, потом при нажатии плюса, минуса, делить или умножить создается второе, а потом все складывается) выводится непонятная вещь.

---

Вот код:

```js
var arrdigit = [];
var arrdigit2 = [];
for (var i = -1; i < 10; i++) {
  $("." + i).text(i);
}


for (var d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
  (function(d) {
    $("." + d).click(function() {
      arrdigit.push(d);
      $(".digit").text(arrdigit.join(""));
    });
  })(d);
}





$(".plus").click(function() {
  totaldigit = arrdigit.join("");
  $(".znak").text("+");
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    (function(j) {
      $("." + j).click(function() {
        arrdigit2.push(j);
        $(".digit").text(arrdigit2.join(""));
      });
    })(j);
  }
});






$(".umnoj").click(function() {
  totaldigit = arrdigit.join("");
  $(".znak").text("x");
  for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    (function(k) {
      $("." + k).click(function() {
        arrdigit2.push(k);
        $(".digit").text(arrdigit2.join(""));
      });
    })(k);
  }
});


$(".delit").click(function() {
  totaldigit = arrdigit.join("");
  $(".znak").text("÷");

  for (var l = 0; l < 10; l++) {
    (function(l) {
      $("." + l).click(function() {
        arrdigit2.push(l);
        $(".digit").text(arrdigit2.join(""));
      });
    })(l);
  }
});





$(".minus").click(function() {
  totaldigit = arrdigit.join("");
  $(".znak").text("-");
  for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    (function(y) {
      $("." + y).click(function() {
        arrdigit2.push(y);
        $(".digit").text(arrdigit2.join(""));
      });
    })(y);
  }
});


$(".equal").click(function() {
  var hn = parseInt(arrdigit.join(""), 10);
  var hm = parseInt(arrdigit2.join(""), 10);
  console.log(hn + hm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Например, при сложении 25 и 31 выводится 2562, хотя я смотрел, typeof (hn и hm) равны number и должны складываться как обычные int'ы. 
С чем это может быть связано и как такое пофиксить?

Comment: с такой ужасной кашей вместо форматированием кода думаешь кто-то захочет помогать? приведи в порядок его

Comment: @evilandrew а лучше на jsfiddle.net залей код